# possible to visually design web application UI on netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

is Netbeans used at all to visually design user interface for web applications? is it possible to use the GUI editor in netbeans to design GWT pages or any database driven web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Google only offers the plugin for Eclipse. If you Google it I'm sure you can find someone who has gotten in to work with NetBeans.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4537/gwt-starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

While technically *possible*, the GUI designer in netbeans is more for Swing (etc.) applications. There are much better editors available for designing the UI for web applications.

That said, while it isn't usually a *good* idea, you *could* have an applet function as a web app and design *that* UI with the netbeans GUI designer.

Comment: what popular UI designer is there for web apps?